# R - dplyr filter - %in% does not behave as expected

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I would like to get explanation on the R's dplyr filter behavior below:

```
df <- data.frame( x = rep('test',3), y = c('service','audio','video') )

filter(df , y == 'service')
#result 1
x      y
test service

filter(df , 'service' %in% y)
#result 2
x      y
test service
test audio
test video
```

Can I get explanation on above behavior? I want to filter out the word service in column 'y'. I do not understand why the row with 'audio' and 'video' get filtered too.

EDIT: I do not understand why I am being flagged down for having this question. I am aware of the difference between '==' and '%in%'. I do not ask the difference between '==' and '%in%' in general. I am wondering why my code does not give the wanted output when using %in% IN dplyr's filter. I am not using %in% randomly and then asking why it behaves that way afterward. Again I am aware of what %in% does. Please see through my question instead of seeing the header only.

EDIT2: As per suggestion, I am changing my header to indicate that my question is different from existing question with similar header.

Comment: `"service" %in% df$y` just gives you a single value, `TRUE`. There's nothing about that expression that makes it go through the rows one by one, it just says "is the value `'service'` in the vector `y`?".

Comment: Perhaps edit the title. As we learned, the issue was incorrect order within the filter argument, which is a different issue to the suggested duplicate.

Comment: @neilfws Thanks for the suggestion. I  am trying it.

Comment: I have edited my question. Will people take back their downvotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, your `%in%` is the wrong way around. But there's not much point in using `%in%` unless you have a character vector with more than one value.

```
df %>% 
  filter(y %in% "service")
  # %in% c("service", "...", "...") would be more usual
```

Comment: thanks man.  I feel stupid in mixing that up. Initially there will be just one value but I want to create a vector variable so I can do this: (y %in% char_vector)